# Responsive images: set sizes attribute from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, responsive-images, srcset

The `srcset` attribute can be set from JavaScript to implement responsive lazy loaded images.

However, setting the `sizes` attribute doesn't seem to work. Coding `sizes` in HTML works as expected, but when I try to set the `sizes` attribute from JavaScript (as in the code below) it has no effect: the image chosen matches the viewport width and doesn't follow the `sizes` hints.

Is this by design, or has this just not been implemented?

Sample code below.

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/foobar/f_auto,dpr_auto,q_auto:eco/';

const SIZES = {
  0: 'calc(100vw - 60px)',
  420: 'calc((100vw - 90px) / 2)',
  750: 'calc((100vw - 120px) / 3)',
  1200: 'calc((100vw - 150px) / 4)'
}

const WIDTHS = [500, 1000, 1500];

const options = {
  rootMargin: '0px 0px 100px 0px',
};

function callback(entries) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const lazyImage = entry.target;
      const id = lazyImage.dataset.id;
      lazyImage.sizes = getSizes();
      lazyImage.srcset = getSrcset(id);
      io.unobserve(lazyImage);
    }
  }
}

function getSrcset(id) {
  const srcset = [];
  for (const width of WIDTHS) {
    srcset.push(`${BASE_URL}w_${width}/${id}.jpg ${width}w`);
  }
  return srcset.join(',');
}

function getSizes() {
  const sizes = [];
  for (const size in SIZES) {
    sizes.push(`(min-width: ${size}px) ${SIZES[size]}`);
  }
  return sizes.join(',');
}

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img.lazy');

let io;
if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
  io = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
}

for (const image of images) {
  if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
    io.observe(image);
  } else {
    console.log('Intersection Observer not supported');
    image.src = BASE_URL + image.getAttribute('data-id' + '.jpg');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your sample and it works fine and as expected for me.

Something is wrong with how sizes are coded, probably.
I think it's not a good idea to put **min-width: 0px** media condition since it will always be selected and all other conditions will be ignored.

From here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

> The browser ignores everything after the first matching condition, so be careful how you order the media conditions.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out. You're right: the implementation here is broken. However, if I change `getSizes()` so it just returns a hardcoded sizes string (with a value that works successfully when coded in HTML) it still doesn't work for me. When you say 'it works fine and as expected', do you mean you've successfully set a sizes attribute from JavaScript?

Comment: Well, images was loaded according to the viewport size. The only thing I found was that it depends on the browser. Firefox always load it properly but Chrome doesn't load new image with lesser size if bigger one is cached. So I had to disable cache with f12 enabled to see that images have really been loaded with proper sizes.

Comment: Regarding 'successfully set a sizes attribute from JavaScript'. It was successfully set, I saw it through F12 inspecting. As I understand it doesn't SET the size of the image. It checks sizes attr and detects which image should be loaded. Or maybe I misunderstood. From that document:  
-Look at its device width.  
-Work out which media condition in the sizes list is the first one to be true.  
-Look at the slot size given to that media query.  
-Load the image referenced in the srcset list that most closely matches the chosen slot size.

Comment: Thanks @akmed0zmey — I got this working by fixing the `sizes` code. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As per @amed0zmey's comment, I fixed this by getting the `sizes` code right.

Working example below.

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://res.cloudinary.com/foo/f_auto,dpr_auto,q_auto:eco/';

const BREAKPOINTS = [0, 420, 750, 1200];
const DISPLAY_WIDTHS = ['calc(100vw - 60px)', 'calc((100vw - 90px) / 2)',
  'calc((100vw - 120px) / 3)', 'calc((100vw - 150px) / 4)'];

const IMAGE_WIDTHS = [500, 1000, 1500];

const options = {
  rootMargin: '0px 0px 100px 0px',
};

function callback(entries) {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const image = entry.target;
      const id = image.dataset.id;
      image.srcset = getSrcset(id);
      io.unobserve(image);
    }
  }
}

function getSrcset(id) {
  const srcset = [];
  for (const width of IMAGE_WIDTHS) {
    srcset.push(`${BASE_URL}w_${width}/${id}.jpg ${width}w`);
  }
  return srcset.join(',');
}

function getSizes() {
  const sizes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i !== BREAKPOINTS.length; ++i) {
    let size = `(min-width: ${BREAKPOINTS[i]}px) `;
    const nextBreakpoint = BREAKPOINTS[i + 1];
    if (nextBreakpoint) {
      size += `and (max-width: ${nextBreakpoint}px) `;
    }
    size += DISPLAY_WIDTHS[i];
    sizes.push(size);
  }
  return sizes.join(',');
}

const images = document.querySelectorAll('img.lazy');

let io;
if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
  io = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
}

for (const image of images) {
  image.sizes = getSizes();
  if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
    io.observe(image); 
  } else {
    console.log('Intersection Observer not supported');
    const id = image.getAttribute('data-id');
    image.srcset = getSrcset(id);
    image.src = BASE_URL + 'id' + '.jpg';
  }
}
```